# Not able to wait for the coroutine to finish using join() in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

I am new to kotlin and coroutines.I have been working on a client-server part of an android app.I am trying to get the routercapabilities using the following code

```
suspend fun getRouterCapabilities(): String? = coroutineScope {
        lateinit var routerRtpCapabilities: JSONObject
        val job = launch {
            socket?.emit("getRouterRtpCapabilities", "", Ack { args ->
                routerRtpCapabilities = args[0] as JSONObject
                Log.d(TAG, routerRtpCapabilities!!.getString("error"))
            })
        }
        job.join()
        Log.d(TAG, "$routerRtpCapabilities")
        return@coroutineScope routerRtpCapabilities.toString()
    }
```

In the above code, I am able to store and print the value of routerRtpCapabilites inside the emit().But I got below mentioned error when I tried to access it from outside the emit().

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property routerRtpCapabilities has not been initialized

And also I am not sure about the way coroutines are used here.Please correct me If I have missed something central.

Comment: What library are you using for the network communication? I temporarily deleted my answer because I noticed `emit` is a callback-based function so my example is incorrect.

Comment: "io.socket.client.Socket"  I used this library for webSocket connections.
In the given code, socket is the instance of a Socket object.
socket.emit( ) requests particular event(in this case it is getRouterCapabilities) and sends the data (here it is none.Thats why I passed empty string as second parameter) to the server and response of server is received as args.From args I need to get the routerCapabilities and return that value as function's return value.But I am getting return value as null due to emit() being asynchronous and this is what I need to resolve

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. I only briefly looked at the library you used, so I haven't tested my code, but it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `job.join()` doesn't wait for the acknowledgement is that the `emit` function launches an asynchronous action and immediately returns. The callback with the result is called later. But the coroutine job doesn't know to wait for some callback, so it immediately completes before the acknowledgement is received sometime later.

When you have a library with an asynchronous function with a callback, you can convert it to a suspend function so it can easily be used in coroutines. Here is how you could convert this emit function:

```
/** Emits the [event] and suspends until acknowledgement is received. Returns the 
acknowledgement arguments. */
suspend fun Socket.awaitEmit(event: String, vararg arg: Any): Array<out Any?> =
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        emit(event, *arg, Ack { args ->
            continuation.resume(args)
        })
    }
```

Some libraries such as Retrofit and Firebase come with suspend function versions of their asynchronous functions, and for those, the above step would be necessary.

A proper suspend function can be called from other suspend functions and in coroutines without doing anything special like wrapping it in another coroutine or `withContext` block.

```
suspend fun getRouterCapabilities(): String? = routerCababilitiesMutex.withLock { 
    val acknowledgement = socket?.awaitEmit("getRouterRtpCapabilities", "") 
    acknowledgement ?: return null // must have null socket
    val result = acknowledgement[0] as? JSONObject
    Log.d(TAG, result?.getString("error") ?: "result is null")
    return result?.toString()
}
```

The `!!` should be changed because it’s unsafe.

To call your suspend function from an Activity, you would do it in a `lifecycleScope` coroutine, for example:

```
mic.setOnClickListener{ 
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val routerCap = someOtherClass.getRouterCapabilities()
        // Do stuff with routerCap here.
    }
}
```

*Edit:* How I would cache the value in your view model class. You can use the mutex to ensure it isn't retrieved redundantly.

```
private var routerCapabilities: String? = null
private val routerCapabilitiesMutex = Mutex()

suspend fun getRouterCapabilities(): String? = routerCapabilitiesMutex.withLock {
    routerCapabilities?.let { return it }
    val acknowledgement = socket?.awaitEmit("getRouterRtpCapabilities", "")
    acknowledgement ?: return null // must have null socket
    val result = acknowledgement[0] as? JSONObject
    Log.d(TAG, result?.getString("error") ?: "result is null")
    result?.toString().also { routerCapabilities = it }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I want to call this method in onCreate() of another class when a mic is clicked.To be precise I want to call it on mic.setOnClickListener{ //val routerCap = getRouterCapabilities() }.Can you give me an idea of how it can be done? Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks a lot.It really worked for me.I do have another doubt.How can I use routerCap value outside the lifecycleScope block?

Comment: There's not really a clean way to do that. You could assign it to a nullable property, but then anywhere you need the value, you would have to check if it's null and if it's not null launch another coroutine to retrieve it. Probably the cleanest way to handle it is to have a nullable property in the class with the suspend function and let the suspend function return the value in the property if it hasn't been retrieved yet. Then always use the suspend function to get the value, and it will return quickly if it's been retrieved before. But you would always use `lifecycleScope.launch` to get it.